# Getting Camera-Like Shutter Flash Effect on Button Click with HTML5 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#skm_LockPane').addClass('LockOn');
  var millisecondsToWait = 100;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#skm_LockPane').removeClass('LockOn');
  }, millisecondsToWait);

});
```

```css
 .LockOff {
   display: none;
   visibility: hidden;
 }
 .LockOn {
   overflow: hidden;
   display: block;
   visibility: visible;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: blue;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 20%;
   filter: alpha(opacity=75);
   opacity: 0.5;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="skm_LockPane" class="LockOff"></div>
<button id="btn">Click!</button>
```

> I am capturing a picture using `getUserMedia` and an HTML5 on button 'Click!'. I need native camera like flash on the screen when the button is clicked. I tried using the code above, but it still lacks that feel. Try the following link, I want an effect similar to this: [Demo](http://facedetection.jaysalvat.com/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use fast CSS transitions and a sound. The effect 'feels' better in full screen

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#shutter').addClass('on');
  $('audio')[0].play();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#shutter').removeClass('on');
  }, 30*2+45);/* Shutter speed (double & add 45) */
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #212121 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFd9s.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 /cover;
  margin: 0;
}
#shutter {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 30ms ease-in;/* Shutter speed */
  position: fixed;
  height: 0%;
  width: 0%;
  pointer-events: none;

  background-color: white;/* Shutter Color */
  
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
#shutter.on {
  opacity: 1;/* Shutter Transparency */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<audio src="http://www.soundjay.com/mechanical/camera-shutter-click-08.mp3"></audio>
<div id="shutter"></div>
<button>Click!</button>
```

Comment: If you see the the flash affect in slow motion (demo url link), the flash starts from center of screen and spread to full window. Like a fedout.

Comment: @GirishKumar Added that, it works by centering the element and then scaling it up quickly. it happens *really* fast so you might have to change the speed to see the effect